# How to declare multiple Literals with only one Literal attribute in F#?

Tags: f#, literals, discriminated-union

I am trying to find an elegant way of assigning keys to symbols without having to do something like the following.

```
let [<Literal>] North = ConsoleKey.UpArrow // etc.
```

I'd rather do something like this, using only one attribute. Is there any way I can do that?

```
[<Literal>]
type Direction =
    | North of ConsoleKey.UpArrow
    | East of ConsoleKey.RightArrow
    | South of ConsoleKey.DownArrow
    | West of ConsoleKey.LeftArrow
```

Comment: The simplest answer is that you need to use multiple Literal attributes. Why do you need a literal (compile time constant) at all in this case? It would help to know more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox It will be used to move a number with in an array and update the position of the number on the console. I don't like seeing repetitive code, it looks like it should be made simpler. But I think I have no options in this case. How would you define these keys to be using in a match expression?

Comment: Have you looked at Active Patterns?

Comment: So I'm guessing you want to use these in a pattern match. That is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your aim is to use these in a pattern match, here is one way to do it:

```
// Use a type alias to shorten the name for ConsoleKey
type Key = ConsoleKey

// Create a general purpose active pattern that simply tests for equality
let (|Is|_|) a b = if a = b then Some () else None

// This is how you would use it
let describeMovement key =
    match key with
    | Is Key.UpArrow -> "up"
    | Is Key.RightArrow -> "right"
    | Is Key.DownArrow -> "down"
    | Is Key.LeftArrow -> "left"
    | _ -> "invalid"
```